# Как качать бинарники в Angular?

Tags: веб-программирование, angular2

В общем, сервер возвращает бинарник в ответ на запрос.

К API я обращаюсь так:

```
  getData() {
    return this._httpClient.get(`${ this.apiUrl }/data`,
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        responseType: 'blob'
      });
  }
```

А потом делаю вот это в subscribe:

```
export class FileDownloader {
     static DownloadFile(data: any, name: string) {
          let blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
          let anchor = document.createElement('a');
          anchor.download = name;
          anchor.href = blobURL;
          anchor.click();
     }
}
```

Но создается такое впечатление, что файл материализуется сразу целиком, т.е когда будет вычитан весь поток.

Такое предположение я делаю из-за того, что браузер не показывает какой-либо прогресс скачивания, а потом через секунд 5 резко в меню скачек появляется готовый файл...

Если это действительно так, то как качать файлы браузером, что бы он отображал прогресс скачки, а неспустя несколько минут молчания появлялся файл? Т.е вот я поставил на скачку файл и снизу на панеле загрузок должен появится файл весом 0 кб, который постепенно набирает вес.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: Ну про прогресс я знаю и это нужно прогресс бар отображать. А браузер сам нативно не может отображать прогресс?

Comment: так я не пойму где связь между браузером и angular? + вопрос звучит `Как качать бинарники в Angular?`

Comment: В последнем абзаце. Я чуть дополнил его.

Comment: Вы определитесь. Вам надо качать файл средствами браузера или через AJAX?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, средствами браузера, если там будет прогресс скачки отображаться в трее.

Comment: Раз вам нужно качать средствами браузера, то не надо использовать AJAX ( `this._httpClient.get`). Вам нужно сформировать ссылку на файл на сервере, и дать пользователю нажать на нее или нажать на нее программно.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko кажется понял. Мне нужно сформировать ссылки прямо на WebApi сачки, вместо ручной скачки.

Comment: Все правильно. Нужна ссылка на скачиваемый файл.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, так а если я не хочу, что бы при наведении на ссылки маячили ссылки на API, это мне программно свои ссылки при клике подменять на апишные и открывать в браузере?

Comment: Да, так тоже можно. А потом создавать тег `a`  и с помощью него скачивать.